# Fancybox plugin and $(window).scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox plugin without image resizing by window height. The gallery images are the right resolution with a height about 800-2000px. So user should scroll every picture in the stack. To make it easier I decided to insert a scrollToTop button. But it didn't work, because fancybox somehow blocks the scroll event. I just tried recreating the scroll event by doing:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('Scroll');
});
```

But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should initialize your scrollToTop button within a fancybox (`afterShow`) callback like :

```
afterShow: function() {
    $("#scrollButtonID").on("click", function() {
        $(".fancybox-overlay").scrollTop(0); // or whatever value
    });
}
```

**Notice** that instead of targeting `$(window)` we are actually moving to the top of the fancybox overlay `$(".fancybox-overlay")`

See this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXm9T/)**

In my DEMO I set the button as an appended element of the fancybox overlay but you could set it as the `title` of fancybox too. For a smoother transition you could `animate` the scroll event, but that is cosmetic ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, JFK! It's great help fo me. I haven't even thought about scrolling `.fanсуbox-overlay`:)

Answer (score 0):

Try binding with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() { 
    alert('Scroll....');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vanilla javascript for this:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    alert('Scroll');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FancyBox - jQuery Plugin 
Version: 1.3.4 (11/11/2010)

line from 1073 to 1083, i disable part of code

```
 /*if ($.fn.mousewheel) {
        wrap.bind('mousewheel.fb', function(e, delta) {
            if (busy) {
                e.preventDefault();

            } else if ($(e.target).get(0).clientHeight == 0 || $(e.target).get(0).scrollHeight === $(e.target).get(0).clientHeight) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.fancybox[ delta > 0 ? 'prev' : 'next']();
            }
        });
    }*/
```